# Cifs Share keeps asking for password and is slow

Tags: mount, password, samba, cifs

I followed the directions here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently
to mount a windows share and it works as expected. Some issues that I am having is one it is very slow when I load the share in the file explorer. In Windows it is almost instant. Another issue I am having is when I edit a file and I Ctrl+S to save the file it asks me for a password every time. I enter my user password for Ubuntu not the Windows share password. I have tried to search Google and haven't come up with any answers. I tried disabling the keychain but keep getting the password dialog. Hopefully someone here can help me solve the issues I am having.

Answer (score 0):

As for the slow file access: I don't know which Samba version you are using, but I suggest to specify the SMB protocol version within the corresponding fstab entry (which is not the case in the examples that the linked article on wiki.ubuntu.com provides). Older Samba versions use SMB1 as standard protocol. Using the outdated SMB1 might slow down folder access, and there are [security issues](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Storage-at-Microsoft/Stop-using-SMB1/ba-p/425858) with SMB1. Add `vers=2.1` to the options in the fstab:

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  username=shareusername,manyotheroptions=andtheirvalues,vers=2.1  0  0
```

If this option is not accepted, it might be necessary to update your cifs-utils. It's most likely that your Windows device supports at least v2.1, but to be safe, you could check on that as well.

As for the password that you have to enter for writing access:
This problem can occur if the username specified in the fstab differs from your Ubuntu username. You could add a share user to your NAS, named identically to the Ubuntu user, and enter this username into the fstab. (There are probably many other approaches to this problem, but this is one of the simplest solutions.)